# Autocomplete from 50k records - which DB solution to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to create an autocomplete to *Rails 5* app with PostgreSQL and I'd have a database with something around 50,000 records available to the user find out (neighborhoods from one entire country). I did some research on web and there are many tutorials outdated and some of them was using `redis` as the best option for this case. So, are there something new that I should follow in these days? Thank you.

Comment: 50k is not that much if your indexes are done right. Why don't you try to implement it in postgres (the easier way) and see if it's good enough?

Comment: you want to autocomplete a html input form?

Comment: [postgresql trigram indexes](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/03/18/fast-search-using-postgresql-trigram-indexes/) will do the trick

Comment: @meta I guess that it can became heavy demand with the user growing

Comment: @inye yes, basically I guess...

Comment: @Fillype Farias yeah, but the data set is fairly constant, and it'll be high read table. You can get away with replication etc.

Comment: @FillypeFarias you know [select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage) (javascript)? You can use this with the ajax option and you have to code to response the select2 ajax query.

Comment: @inye I saw an example with select2 and I felt that it is too slow...but thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @meta yes, I also told that I really wanted to use with this database search, but I'm open to alternatives too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments under the question (writing it down, because users looking for answers usually gloss over comments... I know I do)

- 50k records data set is not that big
- nature of the data set is that it will be rarely updated
- therefore there will be a lot of reads, and almost no writes

So PostgreSQL database should be more than enough, and [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4950680/martin-zinovsky) suggested  [great read about trigram indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49155133/fast-autocomplete-for-rails-app-to-large-records?noredirect=1#comment85316231_49155133) perfect for the task.

If the day comes that there are a ton of users trying to use this autocomplete at once - you should be fine with simple replication.

Comment: Yes it's enough and I ask you only to repair the Tigram link (https://about.gitlab.com/2016/03/18/fast-search-using-postgresql-trigram-indexes/)

Comment: It's a link to @Martin Zinoovsky's comment, I want to keep it that way, to give him credit, because he contributed to this answer.